# Open Graph Action link returning 500 error

Tags: facebook-opengraph, actionlink

I have used open graph Action. Action is working fine. I have also used open graph action link. It showing my link next to unfollow post. but when i click on this action link then ajax call returning 500 error code. I have not received any server to server call on the url.

Comment: Please provide the URL of the action link. Its likely that it's pointing to the wrong place or your site has a 500 error on it.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/ajax/open_graph/actionlink?action_ids=[10150964725240991]&__a=1&__user=650995990                                                    Location url                                   http://fb.locotext.com/geomsg/geomsgtest

Comment: I'm curious to see how you've implemented the action link in your Action settings. Can you provide a screenshot of the settings. I think your problem lies these.

Comment: http://fb.locotext.com/web/action_setting.png              http://fb.locotext.com/web/action_setting1.png

Comment: Q: Do I need to have an https endpoint for my action link?
A: Only if you're not in sandbox mode. If you're developing and have sandbox mode turned on, then our system will simply hit the http:// version of the endpoint you've entered.

Answer (score 1):

I see where the error lies. In order to use the Action Link, Facebook send data to your server using a server-to-server call. The call facebook uses requires SSL / HTTPS, which I see see your server doesn't support. This is why Facebook is returning error 500.

Read the documentation, it says the following:

> Add the endpoint information for your action link. This is the
>   endpoint that will be called when the action link is clicked in a
>   story. This endpoint must match the domain of the app and must be a
>   valid https:// endpoint.

Comment: Is also applicable for sandbox mode?

Comment: Yes. You will need to enable HTTPS for all endpoints, even in sandbox mode. Sandbox mode only function is to hide the app from normal users (i.e. anyone that's not an admin or developer, tester etc of the app).

Comment: I have enabled https for endpoint but still getting 500 internal server error.

Comment: Why is your page forcing the file to be downloaded? That could be your problem.

Comment: Issue is still open. Any response

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but..

Did you check your app Status & Review tab.  You have to add the action and submit your app for reviewal. Facebook will require that with screenshots of your website or platform in order to approve your access to these features.