# Open Graph Action Link URL not invoked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have an **Action Type** configured with an Action **Link** (e.g. Linked Action + Action Link URL). I've verified the URL is secure (https), has a valid SSL certificate and is under the configured **App Domains** for the app.

The Action Type's story is published properly, however when I click on the Action Link, the link turns into an error message:

> There was an error on [MY APP].

On older stories it also says

> Invalid Open Graph Action Link domain for URL ?signed_request=[BASE64 ENCODED REQUEST]

Looking at the Web Server logs, I can verify the request did not reach my server. Is thre any way to debug this issue to understand why the request isn't being sent?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? If so, can you please share that? We are also seeing the same error even on freshly created OG posts. We are using a self-signed SSL certificate for our staging setup, where we are currently seeing this error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in your "invalid...domain for url" issue may be related to having *ever* saved/updated your parent action type while no **Action Link URL** was set.  The admin area indicates you can re-submit for approval but this is apparently not true.  I believe you must delete the action type completely, and create it again.  Problems with action links date [date back to eternity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751936/open-graph-action-link-returning-500-error) and even [stay triaged forever](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173082509515015).  When all else fails, delete both action types (the parent and the linked action), submit for approval, and try again.