# Unexplained Facebook Open Graph 500 response on Action Link click in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Clicking on action links configured in association with open graph actions results in 500 Internal Server Error.

1) this [6 month old bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173082509515015) with Status: Triaged, Priority: Low on Facebook.  **Is Facebook is phasing out Action Links?**

2) a [14-month old stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751936/open-graph-action-link-returning-500-error) still unresolved with the same issue.

Is Facebook's Action Link endpoint "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/open_graph/actionlink" sometimes down?

Our Action Link URL (callback URL, Endpoint, etc) has been tested for and accommodates GET, PUT, and POST.  The documentation does not specify the request method for Facebook action link signed requests.  Nevertheless, the server receives no request.

Some facts:

- Scheme (https) and hostname are identical in the App settings and Action Link URL
- No request is made at our Action Link URL "callback" upon clicking the Action Link using any method (PUT, POST, GET, or even DELETE)
- The 500 is a response to a POST made via ajax to https://www.facebook.com/ajax/open_graph/actionlink
- The related actions, both parent and "linked action", are approved.
- The action link appears in the timeline for both developers and non-developers with no displayed error nor is any UI error raised upon clicking the action link.  There is no "This is not a secure URL" error, etc.

Per Facebook:

**Action Link URL:** *Facebook will send a request to this URL when a user clicks an action link in News Feed.  It must be a secure URL.*

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this bug with facebook and it has since been fixed.